Struggling in Unity2D to duplicate a moving object / bullet passing through a collider?
I've been wracking my brains around a design I want to add into my top down 2D game in Unity, but I cannot find a good approach.
I have a duplicator box, and a bullet travelling towards it.
Bullet Entering Box

Upon hitting/passing through/leaving the box, two bullets are spawned whose offsets have slightly moved from the original bullets path.
Two Bullets leaving box

The behaviour is also that should the bullet hit the duplicator box from a different direction, it will still spawn in the original path/direction.
One bullet entering box from an angle

Two bullets leaving box from the same angle

Asking here as I have a feeling there maybe a really simply way to do this and I've gone a very overcomplicated approach. Any suggestions?
I have already got this working slightly but its bad. I first grab the path/direction of the bullet (on the bullets class itself), instantiate a new bullet, and move the offset of both based on the path of travel.
public float offsetDistance = 0.1f; // Adjust this value to set the offset distance

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Rigidbody2D rb = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    DuplicateObject(other.gameObject);
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
}

void DuplicateObject(GameObject originalObject)
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(originalObject, originalObject.transform.position, originalObject.transform.rotation);
    
    Rigidbody2D originalRb = originalObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Rigidbody2D newRb = newObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
    if (originalRb != null && newRb != null)
    {
        newRb.velocity = originalRb.velocity;
        newRb.angularVelocity = originalRb.angularVelocity;
        
        // Get the normalized direction of travel
        Vector2 directionOfTravel = originalObject.GetComponent<BulletController>().directionOfTravel;
        
        // Calculate the new position with the offset
        Vector2 offset = directionOfTravel * offsetDistance;
        Vector2 newPosition = originalRb.position + offset;
        
        // Apply the new position
        originalRb.position = newPosition;
    }
}


Your code is quite complicated. You just need to duplicate the GameObject, and it will clone all behaviors. You don't need to copy and assign each component individually, such as Rigidbody.
Here is script for Box (Duplicator). it will duplicate the bullet after collider fully inside the box and then split the two bullets. You can enable 'moveToCenter' if you want the bullet move to the center first before duplication. Make sure the box and the bullet collider trigger is enabled. it's basic script to show the concept, you still need to modify it to fit your needs.
public float offsetDistance = 0.1f; // Adjust this value to set the offset distance

public bool moveToCenter;

public Collider2D boxCollider2D;

private bool isDuplicating;

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    
    if (!IsBoundsFullyInside(other.bounds))
        return;
    
    if(isDuplicating)
        return;

    isDuplicating = true;

    if (moveToCenter)
        other.transform.position = transform.position;

    var duplicatedBullet = Instantiate(other.gameObject);
    
    SplitObject(duplicatedBullet.transform, -1);
    
    SplitObject(other.transform);
    
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    isDuplicating = false;
}

private void SplitObject(Transform _transform, int dir = 1) //left -1, right 1
{
    //move towards X Axis
    _transform.position += _transform.right * offsetDistance * dir;
}

private bool IsBoundsFullyInside(Bounds innerBounds)
{
    return boxCollider2D.bounds.Contains(innerBounds.min) && 
           boxCollider2D.bounds.Contains(innerBounds.max);
}

And this is script for bullet movement.
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 movement = transform.up * speed;
    rb2.velocity = movement;
}

see the Result
